# Pythonic way to increment keys and values in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary of keys and values, both of which are ints. Is there an easy and efficient way to increment all the keys and values in the dictionary?

Comment: Why would you increment the keys? This is not the correct use of a dictionary. Just use a list of tuples or something...

Comment: The accepted answer does not modify the existing dictionary, so the answer is **no**.

Comment: Consider using a `collections.deque` instead of a dictionary.  Then the efficient way to increment all the keys is `deque.rotate(1)`.  Handle wrap-around with modulus if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given existing dictionary `d`:

```
d = {k+1: v+1 for k, v in d.items()}
```

This creates a new dictionary. You cannot change dictionary keys in place.

However, first consider whether you really need to create a new dictionary. For example, instead of accessing key `k` of your new dictionary, you could access key `k-1` of your old dictionary, then add one to the value.